# Clickhouse asynchronous_insert_log table not visible

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-go

`asynchronous_insert_log` table is not there under `system` db in clickhouse. My `config.xml` contains below configuration by default:

```
<clickhouse>
<!-- Other settings -->
<asynchronous_insert_log>
        <database>system</database>
        <table>asynchronous_insert_log</table>

        <flush_interval_milliseconds>7500</flush_interval_milliseconds>
        <max_size_rows>1048576</max_size_rows>
        <reserved_size_rows>8192</reserved_size_rows>
        <buffer_size_rows_flush_threshold>524288</buffer_size_rows_flush_threshold>
        <flush_on_crash>false</flush_on_crash>
        <partition_by>event_date</partition_by>
        <ttl>event_date + INTERVAL 3 DAY</ttl>
    </asynchronous_insert_log>
<!-- Other settings -->
</clickhouse>
```

Clickhouse server is running inside docker. I tried setting `async_insert` to 1 and restarted the container. But there was no change.

Do I need to change anything to migrate this to database?

Clickhouse reference documentation:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#server_configuration_parameters-asynchronous_insert_log

Comment: Your XML above is fine. The issue must be with your INSERT statement. How are enabling the setting `async_insert=1`? Try adding it to the INSERT in a SETTINGS clause

Comment: Thanks it worked. I was not aware that table will be visible only after one successful async insert is done. Though I did use SET async_insert=1 before insertion earlier and it did not work then. Not sure why.